# HTML CSS JS minification architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I was exploring some sites for different minification techniques they are using.

I had found most of sites does uses JS minification, concatenation and entire project had one js file which i feel is good technique.

but css and html minification is still only upto removing extra spaces and comments.

But what i found that Google is using some different minification techniques in which they minify the css/html by changing the **selector names in both HTML and CSS.**

I would like to know about this minification architecture google is using. :-)

Comment: You mean [Google Clousure](https://developers.google.com/closure/)? ps: A better thing to do is to *optimize* instead of *minimize* your Javascript code.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm half with you, but in the (new) mobile world where there are limits on the data the client resieved, I think it's also a good practice to minimize your code (last week I minimized a javascript file from 100kb, to 10kb, I also call that optimazation).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 oh really? for me it has been prooven to be successfull doing both

Comment: @Cageman I guess it depends on how large your files are.

Comment: Obviously if you have 2 classes, for example `.button-close` and `.button-validate`, and both of them have `width : 50px;`, optimisation will delete one, and call for the class `.button-close, .button-validate { width : 50px; }`. But also, removing spaces and indentation will reduce the time needed by the server to load the css file so both of these technique are necessary to "minify" a file, what we call minify is a verb that include triming and optimize.

Answer (score 3):

**Advanced CSS minification**

I'm currently using [CSSO](https://en.bem.info/tools/optimizers/csso/description/) minimizer with [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) and [gulp-csso](https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-csso)

> CSSO (CSS Optimizer) is a CSS minimizer unlike others. In addition to
>   usual minification techniques it can perform structural optimization
>   of CSS files, resulting in smaller file size compared to other
>   minifiers.

It works pretty well, the only thing is that you don't win that much on those optimizations.

I would recommend to check out [PageSpeed Tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/), if you're not using it already. This is the best way to see, what kind of asset optimization you really need.

Comment: <tr class="zA yO aqw" id=":if" tabindex="-1">

    <td class="PF xY"></td>

    <td id=":ig" class="oZ-x3 xY" style="">

        <div id=":ih" class="oZ-jc T-Jo J-J5-Ji " role="checkbox" aria-labelledby=":ii" dir="ltr" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">

            <div class="T-Jo-auh"></div>

        </div>

    </td>

in google class are like "zA yO aqw", "PF xY" etc i feel they are using some automated tool which changes the class name in both our css and html file

Comment: i feel they are using some automated tool which changes the class name in both our css and html file

Comment: @veeteshjain [Closure Stylesheets](https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/) and [Closure Template](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/), I've seen some mode user-friendly node modules for that, I'll add a link if I'll find the repository.